# Project migrated from old PC and from VS2010 to VS2012 "The wait operation timed out."

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, windows-7, visual-studio-2012

I just got a new Windows 7 computer with VS 2012. My old box was Windows XP with VS 2010. I copied over my project and had VS2012 upgrade the project and get the following error when running the ASP.NET MVC 3 application:

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)]
>
> [ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
>
> [ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.]

That was the order of the messages. I am connecting through EntityFramework (code first). The connection string was working just fine in VS2010:

```
Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; User ID=xxxxxx; Password=xxxxxxxxx; Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxx; MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

I have been searching for hours with no real solution. The only one I haven't tried is to remove VS 2012 and .NET 4.5. That would be a problem since then I can't code. I have tried to remove .NET 4.5, but then VS2012 doesn't start. I have installed .NET 4.0.

I have installed (only listing software based on what I have see in searches):

- VS 2012
- Windows 7
- SSMS 2010 (which was initially installed after VS 2012)

I have done a repair on VS2012 as well. I have not uninstalled and reinstalled it.

Any thoughts? I am going nuts here. Right now I have a quad-core pc that can remote desktop REALLY fast to my old clunker.

NOTE: My firewall is off. I have Symantec Endpoint Protection and this is connecting to a live SQL server, so I know it's running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazingly, this worked:

```
netsh Winsock reset
```

See [Can't connect to database after installing VS 11 Pro Beta](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/vssetup/thread/2d11b6f9-3ada-4682-b643-c721a97af4ba)